# Logic Apps: What is the "evaluatedRecurrence" trigger property?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Title says it all. The `evaluatedRecurrence` property of Logic App triggers is undocumented and not settable through the logic app designer. It seems redundant.
I can find no answer to this question and not even a similar question. The only thing I can find is in the Readme of [this repo](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator), where the option "IncludeEvaluatedRecurrence" says "this is a non documented object".

So, my question(s) is/are:

- What is this property?
- How does it compare to the "normal" `recurrence` property?
- Does every evaluation count as an action?

Example code:

```
"triggers": {
  "Every_x_minutes": {
    "recurrence": {
      "frequency": "Minute",
      "interval": "@parameters('RunFrequencyMinutes')",
      "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
    },
    "evaluatedRecurrence": {
      "frequency": "Minute",
      "interval": 3,
      "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time"
    },
    "type": "Recurrence"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is this property?

The EvaluatedRecurrence property is when the recurrence trigger is being referenced by any expression or parameter. In general, it remains the same as recurrence unless it doesn't have any references.

> How does it compare to the "normal" recurrence property?

When the trigger is referenced by any expression or parameter it will be evaluated under "evaluatedRecurrence". The "normal" recurrence property is something that will be triggered at times as we scheduled.

> Does every evaluation count as an action?

Not necessarily, unless it is referenced by some parameter.

You can also follow [Can't find the meaning/definition and example of trigger property called "evaluatedRecurrence"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/96194) for further information.